# Github - fetch all forks of a cloned git repo and add as Remote origin

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, branching-and-merging, git-fork

I am looking to fetch all forks and add them as Remote in a cloned repo from Github but couldn't figure out a way to do so.
I have tried with Github Desktop and Sourcetree but couldn't figure out a way to achieve it. Ideally I would like to compare the forks locally(after checking the Network Graph) using Araxis Merge, Delta Walker or Beyond Compare tool and then merge the changes required.

Comment: the first part of the question (and answer) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753590/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-forks-of-a-github-repo-on-linux/58753591#58753591

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?